# SEAM stateless bean not updating

Tags: java, jsf, seam, ajax4jsf

I am trying to implement 'forgot password' functionality using JSF SEAM in our index page, I am using a a4j:jsFunction to send the users email and card number via two 's

It seems to work fine when I just send the email (as a string), but when I added card number (int) it threw the following..

Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @256,138 assignTo="#{forgotPasswordActions.cardnumber}": The class 'org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_5' does not have the property 'cardnumber'.

The backing bean looks like this...

```
@Stateless
@Name("forgotPasswordActions")
public class ForgotPasswordActionsBean implements ForgotPasswordActions, Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Logger private Log log;

    @In private EmailService emailService;
    @In private UserDAO userDAO;
    @In private MessagePoster messagePoster;
    @In private Map<String, String> messages;
    private User user;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private int cardnumber;

    @Override
    public void resetPassword(){
        new RunAsOperation(true) {
            public void execute() {
                if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(email)){
                    user = userDAO.findByEmail(email);
                }
                else{
                    messagePoster.postPopupInfoMessage(messages.get("inputEmpty"));
                }
                if(user!=null && cardnumber == user.getCardId()){
                    String newPassword = generateRandomPassword();
                    log.debug("updating password...");
                    user.setPassword(newPassword);
                    user = userDAO.makePersistent(user);
                    address = user.getEmail();
                    log.debug("password changed to: "+newPassword);
                    Map<String, Object> emailInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    emailInfo.put("name", user.getFirstname());
                    emailInfo.put("newPassword", newPassword);
                    emailService.sendToAddress(Email.user_password_reset, address, emailInfo);
                    messagePoster.postPopupInfoMessage(messages.get("pwReset")+" "+user.getEmail());
                }
                else{
                    messagePoster.postPopupInfoMessage(messages.get("resetFailed"));
                }
            }
        }.run();
    }

    //---------------------- Setters

    @Override
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCardno(int cardnumber) {
        this.cardnumber = cardnumber;
    }

}
```

and the JSF / HTML

```
    <div id="forgotPasswordDialog" title="Forgot Password">
        <div class="textBox">
            <input id="emailLookupval" type="text" />
            <input id="cardNoval" type="text" />
            <button onclick="resetPassword(jQuery('#emailLookupval').val(),jQuery('#cardNoval').val())" type="button">Reset</button>
            <a4j:form id="forgotPassword">
                <a4j:jsFunction name="resetPassword" 
                        action="#{forgotPasswordActions.resetPassword}"
                        oncomplete="jQuery('#forgotPasswordDialog').dialog('open')">
                    <a4j:actionparam name="userEmail" assignTo="#{forgotPasswordActions.email}"  />
                    <a4j:actionparam name="userCardno" assignTo="#{forgotPasswordActions.cardnumber}" />
                </a4j:jsFunction>
            </a4j:form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I cant work out why it wont set this bean property?? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setter is called `setCardno()` while `setCardnumber()` is been expected by the view. The `#{bean.property}` does not relate to property names in the bean. It relates to getter/setter method names. There are 2 ways to fix this:

- Rename the setter method:

  ```
  public void setCardnumber(int cardnumber) {
      this.cardnumber = cardnumber;
  }
  ```
- Or, rename the view property:

  ```
  assignTo="#{forgotPasswordActions.cardno}"
  ```